# Get warning message when using JAVA to get wsdl

Tags: java, wsdl, warnings

I create a web service(asp.net) and our web server is IIS 7.

I add a overloading service today, when java get wsdl and use it, it will show warning message as below.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.model.JavaMethodImpl freeze
WARNING: Input Action on WSDL operation DBService and @Action on its associated Web Method dbService did not match and will cause problems in dispatching the requests
```

My java can get correct data by web service, but how to fix this warring?

Answer (score 0):

The "@action" URL annotated for "DBService" should be same as the 
"soapAction" URL in the "wsdl" with operation "DBService".

Comment: That's understandable but the code is generated like this; how do I go around this?